# how to improve the search relevance order in elasticsearch?

Tags: search, elasticsearch, lucene, match

I am having a field named title which is having values as below

1. apple iphone 6s
2. apple iphone 6
3. apple iphone 6s plus
4. apple iphone
5. apple iphone 5s

So if user searches for

> apple iphone 6

Then it should come in the order as

> 2 > 1 > 3 > 4 > 5

.
and if user searches for

> apple iphone 6s

It should come in order as

> 1 > 3 > 2 > 4 > 5.

How can this be done using elasticsearch.

I have used multi_search and all. But no help.

The order should be exact match first, then prefix. then phrases then field containing all 3 terms and then field containing  2 terms and then field containing 1 terms and so on.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: What is the difference in your opinion between an exact match and a phrase in this scenario?

Comment: if user searches for iphone 6 then also order should be 2 > 1 > 3 > 4 > 5

Answer (score 0):

You can try with:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool":{
      "should":[
        {"match_phrase":{"title":"apple iphone 6s"}},
        {"match_phrase_prefix":{"title":"apple iphone 6s"}}
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

If you want all the data that has "iphone" and "apple", you should add a `match_phrase_prefix` for each word in the search.

Comment: Whether the title field is analyzed or not? what will be the mapping?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get results in the order you specyfied you need to have such query:

```
POST /phone/phone/_search
{
   "query": {
      "bool": {
         "should": [                
            {
               "match_phrase_prefix": {
                  "text": "apple iphone 6"
               }
            },
            {
               "match": {
                  "text": "apple iphone 6"
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

Search query string "apple iphone 6" and results order:

1. apple iphone 6
2. apple iphone 6s
3. apple iphone 6s plus
4. apple iphone
5. apple iphone 5s

Answer (score 0):

I am doing like this below. It is giving me the results in expected way i want.

```
{
    "query": {
        "filtered": {
            "query": {
                "bool": {
                    "should": [{
                        "multi_match": {
                            "query": "apple iphone 6",
                            "fields": ["title"],
                            "operator": "and",
                            "boost": 1
                        }
                    }, {
                        "multi_match": {
                            "query": "apple iphone 6",
                            "fields": ["title"],
                            "type": "phrase_prefix",
                            "boost": 2
                        }
                    }, {
                        "multi_match": {
                            "query": "apple iphone 6",
                            "fields": ["title"],
                            "type": "phrase",
                            "boost": 3
                        }
                    }]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```